# using wiimote accelerometers to control a robotic arm

Tags: c#, wiimote

I am trying to use the wiimote accelerometers to control a robotic arm. I have the buttons workings and currently controlling the arm. Now i want to implement the wiimote accelerometers to control a robotic arm. has anyone worked with the wiimote accelerometers and could give me suggestions on how to implement it.

Comment: Many people have hooked up the wiimote to Arduino's. Look for answers there too.

Comment: What kind of cool job do you have? ;)

Comment: +1 just for the awesomeness of the project!

Answer (score 1):

There is [a managed library for wiimote](http://www.brianpeek.com/page/wiimotelib.aspx).

Also, have a look at this answer: [Using Accelerometer in Wiimote for Physics Practicals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2984469/12744)

Comment: ok i looked at the managed library and created a gui application and i do get the accelerated values. i want to use the accelerated values to drive a servo first. i need to pass the accelerated values in a buffer does any know how to pass a float buffer in c#